# I keep getting syntax error and i don't know why

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, ampl, glpk

Here is my model.

```
set ch ;
set k ;
param a{i in ch , j in k};
param b{i in ch };
param c{j in k };

var x{i in ch , j in k}>= 0;

minimize cost: sum{i in ch , j in k} x[i,j]* a[i,j];

s.t. D{i in ch }: sum{j in k} x[i,j] >= b[i];
s.t. E{j in k }: sum{i in ch } x[i,j] <= c[j];

data;

set ch := ch1 ch2 ch3;
set k := k1 k2;

param a : ch1 ch2 ch3 :=
k1 100 180 100
k2 50 120 80;
param b := ch1 50
ch2 80
ch3 100;
param c := k1 400
k2 90;

solve;

display x{i in ch , j in k};

end;
```

I got the following error when solving the model:

```
cau5.mod:25: syntax error in data section
```

This is really confusing because there is a model that have the same format but solving just fine. Please someone help.

Comment: The error message is for a different AMPL model than you are showing. It has `param a : cha chb chc := ...` while your model has `param a : ch1 ch2 ch3 := ...`.

Comment: Sorry i tried to change 1 ,2 and 3 to a b c to see if it helped. Then i changed it back without recompile it. The error is similar through.

Comment: I found out what was wrong. It's in the `display x{i in ch , j in k};`. First, the syntax is wrong, it's `display x;`. Second, i was not supposed to put it in the data section. I also had row and column keys swapped for `a` too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have row and column keys swapped in the data table for `a`. You can add `(tr)` which means "transpose" to fix this:

```
param a (tr) : ch1 ch2 ch3 :=
k1 100 180 100
k2 50 120 80;
```